# What is `LocalTestServerContext` and how do I get to use it?

Tags: java, google-api, geocoding

I am working with google maps API, specifically geocoding API, and in there example on how to use it, they typed the following :

```
    @Test
  public void testReverseGeocode() throws Exception {
    try (LocalTestServerContext sc = new LocalTestServerContext(reverseGeocodeResponse)) {
      LatLng latlng = new LatLng(-33.8674869, 151.2069902);
      GeocodingResult[] results = GeocodingApi.newRequest(sc.context).latlng(latlng).await();

      assertEquals(10, results.length);
      assertEquals("343 George St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia", results[0].formattedAddress);
      assertEquals(
          "York St Near Barrack St, Sydney NSW 2017, Australia", results[1].formattedAddress);
      assertEquals("Sydney NSW 2000, Australia", results[2].formattedAddress);

      sc.assertParamValue(latlng.toUrlValue(), "latlng");
    }
  }
```

But my android studio does not recognise `LocalTestServerContext` as being a thing. I searched it up on youtube and didn't found anything helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalTestServerContext` is part of [Java Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) **but is used only for testing purposes** (since is defined into `src/test/java/com/google/maps/LocalTestServerContext.java`).

You should include as a dependency, e.g. and **use only for testing**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.18.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I dont think this works for gradle (in my android studio project). I used this instead : 
 ` implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.18.2' `  . Is it ok?

Comment: Also, I cannot use `import com.google.maps.LocalTestServerContext` cause `LocalTestServerContext`  does not exist

Comment: "use only for testing" you can use inside a test not on regular classes (or change the source code but you should be sure you want use that class for real code).